# Web Scraping in Python with a Login Page

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm using this code to try and do some web scraping. I'm trying to access my school grades using requests and beautiful soup and I'm having a lot of trouble logging in. I just get the error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
}

login_data = {
    'name': 'my_username',
    'pass': 'my_password',
    'form_id': 'new_login_form',
    'op': 'Login'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://irc.d125.org'
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    login_data['form_build_id'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'form_build_id'})['value']
    r = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
    print(r.content)
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks so much!

Comment: That error message alone is not useful, you should have a full stacktrace along with that error that provides context.

However, at a guess, the error is likely that `soup.find()` finds nothing and is returning `None`.

Comment: As @TkTech has said, the error is most likely caused be the fact that `soup.find` doesn't find the element you're looking for, and returns `None` as a result. You then effectively do `None['value']`, which causes the error. It could be that the page you are trying to scrape is dynamically populated (via JavaScript, etc) - elements generated in this way are not visible to BeautifulSoup.

Comment: As loaded by `requests.get()`, that page does not contain an item with that name.  If that item is present when viewed with a browser, then it was dynamically created with JavaScript, which `requests.get()` cannot process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the login button is pressed, the site sends an xhr request with the login information. The following should work, just replace your username and password in the space provided.

## Code

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
}

login_data = {
    "UserName": "REPLACE_USER",  # Enter Username
    "Password": "REPLACE_PASSWORD",  # Enter password
    "RememberMe": False,
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://irc.d125.org/Login'
    s.get(url, headers=headers)
    r = s.post(url, data=login_data)
    print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use something to render the javascript of the webpage before posting the data. A good approach to do that is to put your login script inside a `Scrapy` spider in combination with `Splash`:

see https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium. I use it to get my grades from school page, too.